# Mailchimp - Monthly E-Mail (Limit the number of items)

Tags: mailchimp

I am looking to send out a monthly RSS Driven campaign using Mailchimp. 
My clients site is going to post around 30-40 news items in that monthly period and my understanding of mailchimp is that it will send those 40 items in the RSS driven campaign.

Is their anyway to limit the number of items it sends out?

The Merge Tags seems to create an ugly unstyled list. I am using the following code :

```
*|RSSITEMS:|*
<div class="article" style="width:295px; max-width:295px;">
<h3 style="color: #0099ff; font-weight:normal; width:auto;">*|RSSITEM:TITLE|*</h3>
<p style="width:295px;">*|RSSITEM:CONTENT|*</p>
<a href="*|RSSITEM:URL|*"><img alt="Find out more" src="images/article-read.jpg" class="find-out"></a>
</div>
*|END:RSSITEMS|*
```

Hope that makes sense...

Thanks in advance.